# File added twice in source_group after add_custom_command

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake

I'm trying to learn CMAKE for a project I'm working on (v2.8.8). I'm trying to add a custom command to a set of resource files that generates headers from each resource. I then want to add those resources and the generated headers to source_groups in my visual studio 2005 project

Here's what I have so far:

```
SET (MYAPP_RES_FILES
    ${MYAPP_RES_DIR}/file.1
    ${MYAPP_RES_DIR}/file.2
    ${MYAPP_RES_DIR}/file.3
)

MACRO (MYTRANSFORM IN_FILES OUT_HEADERS)
    FOREACH (I ${${IN_FILES}})
        GET_FILENAME_COMPONENT (IN_FILE ${I} ABSOLUTE)
        GET_FILENAME_COMPONENT (OUT_HEADER ${I} NAME_WE)
        SET (OUT_HEADER ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/res/generated/gen_${OUT_HEADER}.h)
        ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND (OUTPUT ${OUT_HEADER}
            MAIN_DEPENDENCY ${IN_FILE}
            COMMAND ${MY_TOOL} -o ${OUT_HEADER} ${IN_FILE}
        )
        SET(${OUT_HEADERS} ${${OUT_HEADERS}} ${OUT_HEADER})
    ENDFOREACH (I)
ENDMACRO (MYTRANSFORM)

SOURCE_GROUP ("res" FILES
    ${MYAPP_RES_FILES}
)

MYTRANSFORM (MYAPP_RES_FILES MYAPP_RES_HEADER_FILES)
SOURCE_GROUP ("res\\generated" FILES
    ${MYAPP_RES_HEADER_FILES}
)

SET (MYAPP_FILES ${MYAPP_FILES} ${MYAPP_RES_FILES})
SET (MYAPP_FILES ${MYAPP_FILES} ${MYAPP_RES_HEADER_FILES})

ADD_EXECUTABLE (${MYAPP_PROJECT_NAME} ${MYAPP_FILES})
```

It seems to work but each of the res files is added twice to their source_group. One without the custom command and one with it. If I remove the `MAIN_DEPENDENCY ${IN_FILE}` line, only one of each resource file is added but they don't have the custom command.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there was an issue adding the resource file to the executable AND to a source group. I dropped the `SET (MYAPP_FILES ${MYAPP_FILES} ${MYAPP_RES_FILES})` and it fixed the issue